# How can I get a union of regex character classes?

Tags: java, regex, clojure

When working with regular expressions, a number of predefined character classes exist:

```
\w          # a word character
\p{Lower}   # a lowercase character
```

(for more details, see [the java.util.regex.Pattern docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)).

How can I define a new character class that is the union of such predefined classes?

Answer (score 0):

Set operations on character classes are well documented in [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html):

```
Character classes

[abc]           # a, b, or c (simple class)
[^abc]          # Any character except a, b, or c (negation)
[a-zA-Z]        # a through z or A through Z, inclusive (range)
[a-d[m-p]]      # a through d, or m through p: [a-dm-p] (union)
[a-z&&[def]]    # d, e, or f (intersection)
[a-z&&[^bc]]    # a through z, except for b and c: [ad-z] (subtraction)
[a-z&&[^m-p]]   # a through z, and not m through p: [a-lq-z](subtraction)
```

besides working on "raw" character classes, we can use this same notation `[...]` for predefined character classes, as the following Clojure examples show.  Here is a simple example using "raw" character classes:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.string :as str]))

(dotest
  (let [alnum (re-pattern "[a-zA-Z0-9]+")]
    (is (re-matches alnum "abc"))
    (is (re-matches alnum "abcDEF"))
    (is (re-matches alnum "abcDEF123"))))
```

and here is a union of predefined character classes:

```
(def symbol-pattern
  #"(?x) # enable expanded form
    [ # union of char classes
      \p{Lower}  # lowercase
      \p{Upper}  # uppercase
      \p{Digit}  # digit
      -_         # hypen, underscore
    ] # end of union
    + # 1 or more
  ")

(dotest
  (is (re-matches symbol-pattern "kebab-case"))
  (is (re-matches symbol-pattern "snake_case"))
  (is (re-matches symbol-pattern "CamelCase")))
```

The above code is based on [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).